# Google Apps Script remove html tags in auto email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need help, again.

I have this script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('calendarApp').setTitle('CalendarApp');
}

function mailOne() {
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()-day+1);
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()-day+8);
  var events2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('myemail@gmail.com').getEvents(firstDay, lastDay);

  var data2 = [];
  data2.push("<b>Title</b>");
  if (events2 && events2.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events2.length; i++) {
      data2.push(Utilities.formatDate(events2[i].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"EEEE dd/MM")+ ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(events2[i].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"HH:mm") +'<br />'+events2[i].getTitle())
    }

 return data2;
  } else {
    return ['Niks te doen!'];
  }
}

function mailTwo() {


  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()-day+1);
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()-day+8);
  var events3 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('myemail2@gmail.com').getEvents(firstDay, lastDay);

  var data2 = [];
  data2.push("<b>Title</b>");
  if (events3 && events3.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events3.length; i++) {
      data2.push(Utilities.formatDate(events3[i].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"EEEE dd/MM")+ ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(events3[i].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"HH:mm") +'<br />'+events3[i].getTitle())
    }

    return data2;
  } else {
    return ['Niks te doen!'];
  }
}

function sendMail(){
 var mail1 = mailOne();
 var mail2 = mailTwo();
 var emailAddress = "myemail@gmail.com";
 var subject = "Je weekplanning";
 var defMessage = mail1 + mail2;


  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, defMessage, {
       name: "Automatisch gegenereerd"
});

}
```

I shows two of my calendars in a html page.

I would like to send an email every week with the output of the two functions. Function sendMail() does it but the emails contain also the HTML tags that are in both functions.

I tried

```
getTextFromHtml(mail1.getBody())
```

But that gives me the error TypeError: can't find function getTextFromHtml in object.

Html replace also doens't work:

```
html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "")
```

I would like to be pointed in the right direction how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You want to send an email as the text by converting the HTML data to text data.
2. You want to send an email as the HTML by rendering the HTML data.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the HTML data is converted to the text data and send it. In order to convert to the text data, in this case, the HTML data is converted to Google Document using Drive API.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows. And before you run the script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

From:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, defMessage, {
       name: "Automatisch gegenereerd"
});
```

To:

```
var tempDoc = Drive.Files.insert({title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, Utilities.newBlob(defMessage, MimeType.HTML)).id
defMessage = DocumentApp.openById(tempDoc).getBody().getText();
Drive.Files.remove(tempDoc);
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, defMessage, {name: "Automatisch gegenereerd"});
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the HTML data is sent as the HTML body. In your script, `defMessage` of `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, defMessage, {name: "Automatisch gegenereerd"});` is sent as the text body. By this, the HTML tags are seen. In order to avoid this, `defMessage` is sent as the HTML body.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, defMessage, {
       name: "Automatisch gegenereerd"
});
```

To:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailAddress, subject: subject, htmlBody: defMessage, name: "Automatisch gegenereerd"});
```

### References:

- [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear explanation. I just checked pattern 2 and that works perfect. Will check pattern 1 later when I have more time.

Comment: @Nina Bakker Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.